# Grauman & Darrells' pyramid match kernel

Tags: computer-vision, histogram

I am student. My assignment is to pick a computer vision paper (from a provided list) and implement its algorithm. I chose Grauman and Darrells' *The Pyramid Match Kernel:
Discriminative Classification with Sets of Image Features* (IEEE, 2005).

I coded the thing up, but it is not matching images well. In fact, I can't even see conceptually how it could work if it uses feature descriptors are sets to match.

The technique, as I understood it, is to create a pyramid of histograms for two feature sets and then compute the (weighted) intersection of those sets. The bin size == 1 for the first level and the bin size doubles at every level of the pyramid. The process stops when bin size >= max_element_in_feature_sets. If bin size where any bigger, the integer division of descriptor_value / bin_size would always return zero and everything would be in one bin.

So here is where it falls apart for me. Imagine that bin size = 1/2 * max_element, that is every element of every feature will go into bin 1 or bin 0. But with a feature vector length of 128 elements, there will still be 2^128 bins. What is the chance of two features into the same bin?

The answer depends, of course. If the features were random noise, the probability would be very low. The paper must tacitly assume that similar images produce similar features. I'm not seeing that in my test runs. For example, I took a gray small image and blurred with a 5x5 Gaussian kernel. Then I compared it to the original image.
Here is the output:
(explanation is below the output. scroll down.)

```
file named art487.jpg extracted features= 50
file named art487_blur.jpg extracted features= 7

Min value= 0, Max val= 164 (of any element)
levels in the pyramid= 8

SUMMARY OF PYRAMID art487.jpg
    level= 0, # bins= 50, bins= 1, 1, 1,..., 1,  count = 50
    level= 1, # bins= 50, bins= 1, 1, 1,..., 1,  count = 50
    level= 2, # bins= 50, bins= 1, 1, 1,..., 1, count = 50
    level= 3, # bins= 50, bins= 1, 1, 1,..., 1, count = 50
    level= 4, # bins= 50, bins= 1, 1, 1,..., 1, count = 50
    level= 5, # bins= 50, bins= 1, 1, 1,..., 1, count = 50
    level= 6, # bins= 50, bins= 1, 1, 1,..., 1, count = 50
    level= 7, # bins= 21, bins= 29, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 50


SUMMARY OF PYRAMID art487_blur.jpg
    level= 0, # bins= 7, bins= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7
    level= 1, # bins= 7, bins= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7
    level= 2, # bins= 7, bins= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7
    level= 3, # bins= 7, bins= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7
    level= 4, # bins= 7, bins= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7
    level= 5, # bins= 7, bins= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7
    level= 6, # bins= 7, bins= 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7
    level= 7, # bins= 4, bins= 4, 1, 1, 1,  count = 7

raw score= 0
normalized score= 0
```

---

The list of number after "bins= " show how many features fell into one particular bin. The results are just is what I expect from 128 dimensions. Every feature gets its own bin, except at the coarsest level, where several zero vectors are grouped together.
This produces a similarity score of 0, just I would expect.

I don't know how to make this pyramid match kernel useful.
The paper says good results were achieved using SIFT features, but there is nothing in the paper to help me understand how that was possible.

What is going wrong? I am supposed to bin pixel intensities and not feature descriptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with a classmate. It turns out the authors used a SIFT feature detector but used 10 dimensional PCA-SIFT descriptors. I'll give that a whirl.
UPDATE: That solved the problem. The features vectors should only be about 10 elements long.

Answer (score 0):

If the bin size is 1/2 * max-size you must add something to your pyramid. It's the same when I lookup for nearest-neighbor in a quadtree and I limit the query to 1/2 of the quadtree. But this method is new to me.